# How to set the initial number of columns in gnome-terminal when opening multiple tabs?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I am trying to output log text to gnome-terminal tabs from the command line. This can be useful for saving session data and later restoring it.

Here is an example:

```
#! /bin/bash

long_text=$(awk "BEGIN { for (i = 1; i < 120; i++ ) { printf \"%s\", \"1234567890\" } }")
cmd="bash -c \"stty cols 159; echo \\\"$long_text\\\"; tput cols; exec bash\""
gnome-terminal --maximize --tab -t A -e "$cmd" --tab -t B -e "$cmd"
```

The problem that I have is that only the last tab (tab B) will initially respect the column width of 159. The first tab (tab A) uses a column width of 80. Here is a screen shot of tab A:

[image]

And here is tab B:

[image]

How can I output text also to tab A using 159 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the profile preferences to match your requirements quite easily.
Choose edit->Profile preferences from the menu and adjust to match your requirements as shown below.
 [image: custom default]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly :) Wonder why tab B still got the correct terminal size..

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a generic solution using command-line, you can try `fold` to change the width of the column.

The format is:

```
fold --width=width_of_column filename
```

For example:

```
fold --width=120 file.txt
```

This will make the width of the column as `120`.

Here is a test:

```
$ head -1 file.txt | wc -m
143
$ head -1 file.txt | fold --width=130 | wc -l
2
$ head -1 file.txt | fold --width=130 | head -1 | wc -m
131
```

Here `131` is due to the inclusion of `\n` in first line while counting by `wc`.

Check [`man fold`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fold.1.html) to get more idea on `fold`.

Comment: Yes fold is also working for my case! Thanks for the tip! I think  there is another issue when width is smaller than some of line lengths in `file.txt` if that file contains UTF-8, lines are split at byte positions and that can corrupt the output..

Comment: Glad it worked..i did not face the issue, will have a look..although should mention that there is an option `--bytes` of `fold` that will count bytes.